# React.js: Function passed from parent component to child component not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

I'm a beginner and trying to learn React. I have a parent component with a boolean in its state that I change with a function defined in its class called rerender(). I pass this function down into a child component's props like so:

```
<Todolist
  color={color}
  name={name}
  items={items}
  addListItem={this.addListItem}
  rerender={() => this.rerender}
/>
```

I have a console.log in that function to check if it is being called. I call it in the child component like this:

```
this.props.rerender();
```

I'm certain that the onChange event which calls `this.props.rerender()` in the child component is firing, so what are some possible reasons as to why it isn't being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will not work hence the function is not called, 2 options:

```
 rerender={() => this.rerender()}
```

or

```
 rerender={this.rerender}
```

the latter one gets any arguments passed to it, but the first one won't get any arguments.

You may need to `bind` the `this.renderer` if it's not defined as an arrow function.